# Optimizing MySQL query with subselect

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, relational-database

I am trying to make the following query run faster than 180 secs:

```
SELECT 
    x.di_on_g AS deviceid, SUM(1) AS amount
FROM
    (SELECT 
        g.device_id AS di_on_g
    FROM
        guide g
    INNER JOIN operator_guide_type ogt ON ogt.guide_type_id = g.guide_type_id
    INNER JOIN operator_device od ON od.device_id = g.device_id
    WHERE
        g.operator_id IN (1 , 1)
            AND g.locale_id = 1
            AND (g.device_id IN ("many (~1500) comma separated IDs coming from my code"))
    GROUP BY g.device_id , g.guide_type_id) x
GROUP BY x.di_on_g
ORDER BY amount;
```

Screenshot from EXPLAIN:
https://ibb.co/da5oAF

Even if I run the subquery as separate query it is still very slow...:

```
SELECT
        g.device_id AS di_on_g
    FROM
        guide g
    INNER JOIN operator_guide_type ogt ON ogt.guide_type_id = g.guide_type_id
    INNER JOIN operator_device od ON od.device_id = g.device_id
    WHERE
        g.operator_id IN (1 , 1)
            AND g.locale_id = 1
            AND (g.device_id IN (("many (~1500) comma separated IDs coming from my code")
```

Screenshot from EXPLAIN:

ibb.co/gJHRVF

I have indexes on `g.device_id` and on other appropriate places.

Indexes:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM guide;
```

ibb.co/eVgmVF

```
SHOW INDEX FROM operator_guide_type;
```

ibb.co/f0TTcv

```
SHOW INDEX FROM operator_device;
```

ibb.co/mseqqF

I tried creating a new temp table for the ids and using a `JOIN` to replace the slow `IN clause` but that didn't make the query much faster.

All IDs are Integers and I tried creating a new temp table for the ids that come from my code and JOIN that table instead of the slow IN clause but that didn't make the query much faster. (10 secs faster)

None of the tables have more then 300,000 rows and the mysql configuration is good.

And the visual plan:
[Query Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3tAC.png)

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Generally: never assume you have all the indexes you need (as you probably don't), so add them, preferable as the output of `show create table guide` . Also for any optimization question, add at least your explain output (write `explain` infront of the query and post the result). Some questions: Do you need the joins? Meaning: Are there any values in `g.guide_type_id` that don't exist in `operator_guide_type` (and same for `g.device_id` and `operator_device`). Can they be `null`? Can `g.operator_id IN (1 , 1)` contain more than 1 value (or is it actually `= 1` or one other single value?)

Comment: Solarflare, thank you, please see my edited answer.

Comment: If I remove the second join the query is much faster, but the results are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's focus on the subquery.  The main problem is "inflate-deflate", but I will get to that in a moment.

Add the composite index:

```
INDEX(locale_id, operator_id, device_id)
```

Why the duplicated "1" in

```
g.operator_id IN (1 , 1)
```

Why does the `GROUP BY` have 2 columns, when you select only 1?  Is there some reason for using `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`.  (The latter seems to be your intent.)

The only reason for these

```
INNER JOIN operator_guide_type ogt ON ogt.guide_type_id = g.guide_type_id
INNER JOIN operator_device od ON od.device_id = g.device_id
```

would be to verify that there are guides and devices in those other table.  Is that correct?  Are these the PRIMARY `KEYs`, hence unique?:  `ogt.guide_type_id` and `od.device_id`.  If so, why do you need the `GROUP BY`?  Based on the `EXPLAIN`, it sounds like both of those are related 1:many.  So...

```
SELECT g.device_id AS di_on_g
    FROM  guide g
    WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM operator_guide_type WHERE guide_type_id = g.guide_type_id )
      AND EXISTS( SELECT * FROM operator_device WHERE device_id = g.device_id
      AND g.operator_id IN (1)
      AND g.locale_id = 1
      AND g.device_id IN (...)
```

Notes:

- The `GROUP BY` is no longer needed.
- The "inflate-deflate" of `JOIN` + `GROUP BY` is gone.  The Explain points this out -- 139K rows inflated to 61M -- very costly.
- `EXISTS` is a "semijoin", meaning that it does not collect *all* matches, but stops when it finds *any* match.

"the mysql configuration is good" -- How much RAM do you have?  What Engine is the table?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me with this. The query now takes 1.4 secs.  The ogt.guide_type_id and od.device_id are not primary keys - the operator_guide_type table can have more than one guide_type_id in it - same for operator_device and device_id, but this doesn't seem to affect the query result a lot. ( in 3 rows out of 1219 the total guides amount value is bigger with 1). I am not sure what is causing this. But all other values are the same as the result from the slow query.

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` look like now?  (I'm not sure 1.4s is as low as it can get.)

Comment: https://ibb.co/nr2c5Q - please see the sceenshot :) 1.4 is great !! I ended up using one join and one EXISTS.

Comment: Well, you are still exploding to 920K rows, then imploding to 46K.  Why do you need the one `JOIN`?  That's what is making it as high as 1.4s.  (I think.)